Generic path param causing mismatch routes in Nest.JS
Due to a generic endpoint, I've found myself having an issue:

  @Get(':id')
  async findOne(@Param('id') id: string) {
    return this.categoryService.findById(id);
  }

  @Get('findByKeywords')
  async findByKeywords(@Query('keywords') keywords: string): Promise<any[]> {
    this.logger.log(`Received keywords: ${keywords}`);
    return this.categoryService.findByKeywords(keywords);
  }

When trying to reach the 2nd endpoint listed above, the request instead goes to the first one due to the generic path param ":id".
Simply changing the URL of the first one to something specific such as
"by-id/:id"
Or simply swapping their order makes it work properly, but that doesn't seem to be a good idea overall since I can end up having this issue in the future as well.
Is there a way to avoid this issue for future endpoints or is this really how it's supposed to work?

There are no other solutions for that.
Nest uses Express.js under the hood. And it will use the first matching route.
You just have to keep a proper order of the routes.
